# Why is Qg4-Qe6 the correct move here?

Tags: analysis, learning

Given this board setup:

```
6k1/1p3rpp/1q1p4/p2Pp3/P5Q1/1P3PP1/2R3KP/8 w - - 3 13
```

Puzzle states: White to move, find the best move. The puzzle solution says Qg4-e6 and the rationale is that Rc2-c8+ cannot be stopped.  It seems to me, and some computer programs agree, that going directly for Rc2-c8+ is better because it forces a response of Qb6-d8 followed by Rc8xd8+ Rf7-f8, Qg4-e6+ Kg8-h8, Rd8xf8#. I am no master, I barely can call myself novice. So why is the solution saying that Qg4-e6 is better?

Comment: I prefer Rc8 as it is more forcing. I don't see the advantage to `1. Qe6`

Comment: What is the stipulation of the puzzle?

Comment: @jknappen what do you mean by stipulation?  The problem states "white to move, find the best move".  Does that answer your question?  I guess I should have included that wording in the question.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, it does. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @jknappen Thanks for pointing that out.  I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right. Qe6 only seems to draw:

```
6k1/1p3rpp/1q1p4/p2Pp3/P5Q1/1P3PP1/2R3KP/8 w - - 3 13

1. Qe6 g6 2. Rc8 Kg7
```

There's no forced win for white here as far as I can see.

Comment: Do you have a link or reference for creating those boards in questions and answers?  I looked through the help but struck out.

Comment: @Matt: check [this question](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post) on Chess Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Often there are several strong moves and the puzzle solution lists just one of them.

In this case however, it seems to be a mistake. Possibly the second move was given instead of the first, with the intended solution being 1.Rc8 Rf8 2.Qe6+.